# How to Read SMPP UDH message

Tags: java, tcpdump, smpp

I am new to SMPP protocol usage, I am getting message in my log as below.

`Sending UDH Message...`

`SMPP UDH 0500031B0301004D00`

**How can I convert the UDH message to a normal text** (`Java Program` or `Tool`).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16363107/467545 - it describe how to encode UDH. Just do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

UDH is not meant to be interpreted as text. It's because it will contain non printable characters like `0x00` or `0x01`. It ought to be decoded byte by byte. More details about UDH is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header

However if you don't want to get into the complexity involved with bits and bytes you can instead use a *network capture* tool like [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) to capture the smpp packet and then use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to do the decoding for you.